# Ac adaptor of laptop with different amp

Tags: laptop

I replaced my laptop charger with new one

Old charger:

- input 100~200v (1.5a)
- output 19v (3.45a)

New charger:

- input 100~200v (1.4a)
- output 19v (4.25a)

Can I use the new charger? Will the input amperage harm my laptop?

Comment: Your question has been rolled back. Changing your question after you've received answers is inappropriate, as it invalidates the answers you've received. It can even make those answers wrong, and adversely affect the reputation of those who answered. If you now have a new or additional question, create a new post and ask it there.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the voltage and plug are correct and both products are working properly, yes it should work fine. Current (amperage) if pulled by the device, not pushed by the source, so the device should only draw how much current it needs up to the limits of the source.

Comment: There is the caveat that the new adapter should not have, eg, 10x the current rating of the old one, as it may need a certain minimum current draw to regulate accurately.

Comment: True... But I did not see that as a possible issue in this case.